# My laptop connect to wireless router but wont connect to internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet

My laptop has `Windows 7` and connects fine when connected via an Ethernet cable to a router and my mobile works fine connected wirelessly. But, when I try to connect my laptop wirelessly, it does not connect and shows following messages: `Unidentified network` and `No internet access`

**EDIT:**

When I run `ipconfig` in command prompt I get following output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2515:3ba9:394c:8aac%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{ABD0802E-8927-40FA-8D1B-219BA485D25D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{144CC641-E1B3-468C-A79E-0D3C8D1C296A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2345DBD9-83D2-486C-8DD7-988E93E9C3D5}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: I'm going to assume you've restarted the router, can you run a command prompt and type in ipconfig and tell us what your ip address is.

Comment: @Col I restart the router, it's don't correct. I also added result of `ipconfig` command in original my question.

Comment: For some reason you haven't got a default gateway, it's possible you've set a manual ip address on your wireless card. Do you know how to change the properties of your wireless lan card?

Comment: @Col No, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you

1. go to control panel then view network status and tasks.
2. Click Change adapter settings
3. Right click on the wireless network and choose properties
4. Double click on internet protocol v4
5. Make sure both settings (IP address and DNS) are set to automatic.

Comment: Wow, Thanks Col, It corrected and worked fine. Col, I have another question: Is ther any book or web site for learning network for users such as me that haven't any information from networking?

Comment: Glad to help, as far as books go, I don't really know most of what I've picked up is just experience over 20 years of user support. w3schools.com have basic courses that cover a broad base including basic tcp/ip which is what we were looking at.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic and easy to read book to begin with would be " Networking for Dummies". I'm not at all trying to suggest you are less than intelligent, its just the name of the book. I own it myself and it has a lot of good and simple explanations in it. You can often find it at a used book store for just a few bucks.